# Why can't a list be constructed and modified in the same line?

Tags: python, list

For example, why is `a` not equal to `b`?

```py
a = [1]
a.append(2)
print(a)  # [1, 2]

b = [1].append(2)
print(b)  # None
```

The syntax for `b` doesn't look wrong to me, but it is. I want to write one-liners to define a list (e.g. using a generator expression) and then append elements, but all I get is `None`.

Comment: The list `append()` method modifies the list in-place so it doesn't return anything (which is equivalent to returning `None`) — which you're assigning to `b` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one-liner for `b` does these steps:

1. Defines a list `[1]`
2. Appends `2` to the list in-place
3. Append has no return, so `b = None`

The same is true for all `list` methods that alter the list in-place without a return. These are all `None`:

```py
c = [1].extend([2])
d = [2, 1].sort()
e = [1].insert(1, 2)
...
```

If you wanted a one-liner that is similar to your define and extend, you could do

```py
c2 = [1, *[2]]
```

which you could use to combine two generator expressions.

Comment: You could create your own list-like that implements `insert`, `append`, etc by returning the list object, then `a = MyList.from_list([1]).append(3).insert(2, 1)` would work.

Comment: You can use `itertools.chain` to make one generator from multiple generators and feed it to `list()`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because:

`append`, `extend`, `sort` and more list function are all "in-place".

What does "in-place" mean? it means it modifies the original variable directly, some things you would need:

```
l = sorted(l)
```

To modify the list, but `append` already does that, so:

```
l.append(3)
```

Will modify `l` already, don't need:

```
l = l.append(3)
```

If you do:

```
l = [1].append(2)
```

Yes it will modify the list of `[1]`, but it would be lost in memory somewhere inaccessible, whereas `l` will become `None` as we discovered above.

To make it not "in-place", without using `append` either do:

```
l = l + [2]
```

Or:

```
l = [*l, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

All built-in methods under class 'List' in Python are just modifying the list 'in situ'. They only change the original list and return nothing.

The advantage is, you don't need to pass the object to the original variable every time you modify it. Meanwhile, you can't accumulatively call its methods in one line of code such as what is used in Javascript. Because Javascript always turns its objects into DOM, but Python not.